# How to solve SAXParseExecption in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application,In my application,I am displaying lot of images from url using `DOM` xml parsing,It is working fine,but some time i got `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of the document`in my xml parsing handler.How to solve this problem,please help me.This is my xml parsing handler code

```
public String parse_bannerlink() throws UnknownHostException{
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
String bannerlink=null;
try {
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(this.getInputStream());
org.w3c.dom.Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("partypicbanner");
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
Node item = items.item(i);
NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
Node property = properties.item(j);
String name = property.getNodeName();
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
bannerlink=property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
}}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
return bannerlink;
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely not parsing that document using `DOM` you are parsing it using `SAX`. I'd check the document you are trying to parse as apparently that document is not valid.

**UPDATE:** Apparently I was wrong. Didn't know that DOM throws that exception too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate your input file with any xml-validator, for example this: [Xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp)